# Casting or converting a char to an NSString in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, char

How do I convert a char to an NSString in Objective-C?

Not a null-terminated C string, just a simple `char c = 'a'`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `stringWithFormat:`, passing in a format of `%c` to represent a character, like this:

```
char c = 'a';
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks BoltClock. I'm new to Objective-C and alot of this stuff is a bit undiscoverable to me at the moment. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Hovito: If you use Xcode, remember there's always the built-in documentation viewer :)

Comment: stringWithFormat is an overkill, IMHO.

Comment: @Seva: Yeah I agree, I'm guessing it's because of the extra NSString containing the format. I upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 8):

You can make a C-string out of one character like this:

```
char cs[2] = {c, 0}; //c is the character to convert
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:cs encoding: SomeEncoding];
```

Alternatively, if the character is known to be an ASCII character (i. e. Latin letter, number, or a punctuation sign), here's another way:

```
unichar uc = (unichar)c; //Just extend to 16 bits
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&uc length:1];
```

The latter snippet with surely fail (not crash, but produce a wrong string) with national characters. For those, simple extension to 16 bits is not a correct conversion to Unicode. That's why the `encoding` parameter is needed.

Also note that the two snippets above produce a string with diferent deallocation requirements. The latter makes an autoreleased string, the former makes a string that needs a [release] call.